# android: In a Layout how to dynamically add 2 rows in the same column and then add the next 2 rows in the next column and so on

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-tablelayout

I have a RecyclerView which inflates a layout to display products.. I need your help to display a vertical list of products but with 2 products displayed horizontally on the same line and the next two products below them should be displayed horizontally and so on.. here is my xml.. I need to inflate it in such a way that I am able to achieve the above mentioned task.. please help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:id="@+id/product_list_ll"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_name"
                android:text="Product name"
                android:textColor="@color/appBasic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wishlist"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
                android:text="@string/fa_heart"
                android:layout_gravity="right|end"
                android:gravity="right|end"
                android:textColor="@color/appBasic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:id="@+id/product_price"
                android:text="Product price"
                android:textColor="@color/appBasic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_name"
                android:id="@+id/product_id"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="Product price"
                android:textColor="@color/appBasic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_price"
                android:id="@+id/product_discount_price"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:text="Discount price"
                android:textColor="@color/appBasic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) instead?  It would simplify your code and improve the performance 10 fold vs dynamically added table rows.

Comment: Hi, Gary thanks for your reply.. if you could provide me with a link of how to do it.. it would help me alot

Comment: The Android GridView documentation has an example in there, there are a ton more google hits as well:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm